# Why doesn't the function taxonomy_term_search exists?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

I have an autocomplete field in an API Form. The callback function uses the following code to highlight the search query in the list of suggestions.
With a taxonomy vocabulary of 3 levels of hierarchy, about 8,000 terms, it takes a whole eternity of 1 second to offer the suggestions. In a direct SQL query or a EntityFieldQuery it takes just a few tenths of a second. Why doesn't **mixed $tid_array =** `taxonomy_tearm_search(term_name, vid)` exists, it would increase the code below in which only taxonomy API is used.

```
mymodule_providers_autocomplete($brand, $text){ 
   $selected_providers = array();
   $providers = get_providers_of_type($brand);
   $counter = 0;
   foreach($providers as $nid => $provider){
      if(strpos(strtoupper("." . $provider["title"]), strtoupper($text)) > 0){
           $selected_providers[$provider["title"] . ' (' . $nid . ')'] = str_ireplace($text, "<strong>" . $text . "</strong>" , $provider["title"]);
           $counter++;
           if($counter > 10) break; 
       } // if
   }
 drupal_json_output($selected_providers);
} // function

function get_providers_of_type($brand){
   $children_1 = taxonomy_get_children($brand);
   $models_arr = array();
    foreach($children_1 as $key2 => $value2){
        $children_2 = taxonomy_get_children($value2->tid);
        foreach($children_2 as $key => $value){
            $models_arr[] = array("title" => $value->name);
        } // foreach
    } // foreach
}   // if
  return $models_arr;
} // function
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it does not exist because either no one wrote it, or maintainers found it not suited for inclusion in [taxonomy.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/7) for whatever reasons. For most purposes, `taxonomy_get_term_by_name` is enough. When it's not, there are various search solutions in separate, search oriented modules.

If you think you can write it, and make it good, please do so, and then post entry in issue queue with appropriate patch file.

Comment: This is the only objective answer possible for this question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I just hope I don't sound too harsh or something and don't get too much downvotes for it. But oh well.

Comment: I have tried `taxonomy_get_term_by_name` as proposed by Molot. Apparently it should do what I am looking for, but I can only make it work with exact name and without the **vid** numeric value. I have also tried with `%` or `*` characters, but still it doesn't work as a search term. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Cesar that's because % and * are perfectly valid characters in term's name, and thus are interpreted literally.